# Top 10% on a disliked tag. Could we hide tags on Careers profile?

Tags: support, tags, jobs, ignored-tags

[My profile on careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/pascal-martin) show that I am Top 10% on the [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) tag.

While I might have answered [a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:138475%20%5Basp.net%5D) *(well, not that much: only 15)* that were tagged as [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net), I know almost nothing of it -- and I am absolutely not looking for any kind of [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) related job.

I have tried setting that tag as a disliked one ; but it still appears in the Top 10% list.

**Would it be possible to exclude some tags from the Top X% lists ?**

*Either by setting them as disliked, or by another mean ?*

Here's a screenshot of the top of my profile, in public view, that shows what I'm posting about :

[image: unwanted tags in top 10% list]

Comment: Wow. After looking at your profile, that "Top 10%" seems like it must be nearly meaningless. Multiple people have more points in that tag in the last 30 days than you do overall. What's even the point?

Comment: Yeah, that tag, in my case, is a perfect example of how "top 10%" can be wrong ^^ ; I suppose it's due to the fact that some of my answers have gotten quite a few upvotes *(but my answers were generally not specific to asp.net, and would have been true for any other language -- which is why I knew good answers)*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you click the second "edit" link* on your profile's edit view, it gives you the option of selecting which tags you want displayed, and whether or not you'd like anything to be displayed at all:

[image: Tag percentile selection]

<sub>*After this question was posted, the edit link was moved so that it was closer to the actual tags, making it easier to find.</sub>

Comment: Ooops, never quite noticed that link nor though it would edit the tag *(as it's on the right side of the photo)* ; That's exactly what I was looking about, thanks !

Comment: Yeah, the placement is a bit confusing. I actually found it the first time by accident, after clicking it trying to figure out what it was for.

Answer (score 7):

I got a nibble that appeared to be related to my positions as an "expert" in a tag that I know nothing about, too.

You can edit which tags are shown using the lower button beside your avatar...
[image]

Comment: Two answers in 4 minutes, both during the same minute ; I definitely love SO/meta ! Thanks for your answer :-)